# yii2 ошибка в функции при валидации пароля

Tags: php, yii2

```
yii\base\Security::validatePassword('123qweASD', '46e44aa0bc21d8a826d79344df38be4b')
```

Заходит сюда:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\$2[axy]\$(\d\d)\$[\.\/0-9A-Za-z]{22}/', $hash, $matches)
            || $matches[1] < 4
            || $matches[1] > 30
        ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Hash is invalid.');
        }
```

Пишет `invalid Hash`

Помогите разобраться в причине.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Думал что сравнивает с хэшем в md5...оказалось не так.